# Point folder root URL to file using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

In my document root I have a subfolder `link` such that `domain.com/link/something` points to `domain.com/link/default.php?id=something`

In my `.htaccess` file (located in the subfolder `link`), I have the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /default.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work as `domain.com/link/something` gives a 404 error. Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples please try following .htaccess rules file.

***Make sure:***

- Keep your .htaccess rules file, default.php files along with your link folder.
- clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```bash
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /link/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ default.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```